# Histogram based on buckets

Tags: python, sorting, histogram, ranking

My data looks in the following manner (space separated):

```
A   B
492 67
501 67
507 67
510 0
51  67
516 0
522 0
525 67
528 0
56  0
542 675
548 0
551 65237
556 0
562 446
568 447
575 4461
581 4464
591 44614
602 4464
```

`What I would like to see is a histogram of A's that gives 90% of all B's.`

Here is what I've tried.
The dual-list dataset

```
dataset = [[],[]]
```

consists of the contents of A in dataset[0] and contents of B in dataset[1].

I created the element num_buckets so that I can push the data based on ranks to the buckets list.

```
def parse_dataset(dataset):
    sums = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    for s in range(1, len(dataset)):
        sums[s] =  sum(dataset[s])
    for a in range(0, len(dataset)):
        rankdict = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(sorted(set(dataset[a])))}
        ranked = [rankdict[b] for b in dataset[a]]
        sorted_rank = sorted(zip(ranked, dataset[0]))
        max_rank = max(ranked)
        min_rank = min(ranked)
        num_buckets =  (max(ranked) - min(ranked)) / 9
        buckets = [[] for q in range(num_buckets)]
        for z in range(0, len(sorted_ranks)):
            if min_rank =< sorted_ranks[z][0] < 9:
                buckets[0].append(sorted_ranks)

                ....
```

Please let me know if some important information is missing out.

Comment: Are you originally a Matlab user? If so you could try out the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). Note that it relies upon the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good plotting option would be to try out the [matplotlib package](http://matplotlib.org/). Note that it relies upon the [numpy package](http://www.numpy.org/).
There are numerous examples on how to do different graphs there. If you want more on how to parse your data, comment here and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: That would be great. any starters would be appreciated.

Comment: So, what i'm visualizign is a bucket based plot of reuse of B's based on A. am i clear?

Comment: Sorry I was completely overwhelmed with work back then. @pistal did you get it sorted?